# Where do i get parts for diy hardware wallet and program

Tags: wallet

I would like to know where to buy hardware for bitcoin wallet and program

Answer (score 3):

> Where do i get parts for diy hardware wallet and program

By DIY I guess you mean not a pre-built product like a Trezor.

Any electonics store or distributor (Mouser, Farnell, etc etc etc) will sell you parts to make any of the open-source options listed in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardware_wallet

To pick a random easy example: [pi-wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardware_wallet#Pi_Wallet_-_cold_storage) - though a compute-module or zero-W would be more compact. There's plenty of open-source hand-held, battery-powered [gaming devices based on that hardware](https://retrododo.com/retropie-handhelds/) that could be adapted to suit.

If you are more ambitious, and handy with a soldering iron, you could check out something like [BitBox](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/bitbox02-firmware) which is apparently based on standard electronics parts. They publish schematics and bill-of-materials for parts as well as the code. You'll not match their production quality but a functional portable device should be achievable with the right skills.